# Generating CPU utilization levels

Tags: cpu-usage

First I would like to let you know that I have recently asked this question already, however it was considered to be unclear, see [Linux: CPU benchmark requiring longer time and different CPU utilization levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967093/linux-cpu-benchmark-requiring-longer-time-and-different-cpu-utilization-levels). This is now a new attempt to formulate the question using a different approach.

**What I need:** In my research, I look at the CPU utilization of a computer and analyze the CPU utilization pattern within a period of time. For example, a CPU utilization pattern within time period 0 to 10 has the following form:

```
time, % CPU used 
0   , 21.1
1   , 17
2   , 18
3   , 41
4   , 42
5   , 60
6   , 62
7   , 62
8   , 61
9   , 50
10  , 49
```

I am interested in finding a simple representation for a given CPU utilization pattern. For the evaluation part, I need to create some CPU utilization patterns on my laptop which I will then record and analyse. These CPU utilization patterns that I need to create on my laptop should

1. be over a time period of more than 5 minutes, ideally of about 20 minutes.
2. the CPU utilization pattern should have "some kind of dynamic behavior" or in other words, the % CPU used should not be (almost) constant over time, but should vary over time.

**My Question:** How can I create such a utilization pattern? Of course, I could just run an arbitrary program on my laptop and I will obtain a desired CPU pattern. However, this solution is not ideal since a reader of my work has no means to repeat this experiment if wanted since he has not access to the program I used. Therefore it would be much more beneficial to use something instead of an arbitrary program on my laptop (in my previous post I was thinking about open source CPU benchmarks for example). Can anyone recommend me something?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a moving average. Select a window size and use it to average over. You'll need to decide what type of patterns you want to identify since the wider the window, the more smoothing you get and the fewer "features" you'll see. And CPU activity is very bursty. For example, if you are trying to identify cache bottlenecks, you'll want a small window, probably in the 10ms to 100ms range. If instead you want to correlate to longer term features, such as energy or load, you'll want a larger window, perhaps 10sec to minutes.

It looks like you are using OS provided CPU usage and not hardware registers. This means that the OS is already doing some smoothing. It may also be doing estimation for some performance values. Try to find documentation on this if you are integrating over a smaller window. A word of warning: this level of information can be hard to find. You may have to do a lot of digging. Depending upon your familiarity with kernel code, it may be easier to look at the code.